# Using count to isolate record according to number of appearance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables, Avatar, Super_Avatar and Trade.

Trade attributes  = avName | buyerID | sellerID...
Avatar attributes = avName | DOB | gender...
Super_Avatar attributes =  avName | wisdom..

there are all connected by avName. Trades table represents how many times an avatar has been traded. I used the count to isolate the number the avatar has been traded(by counting how many times a particular avatar(avName) appears in traded table). I only want those that appear more than twice.

```
SELECT avName
INTO tempTable
FROM Trade
GROUP BY avName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

How do I join the temporary table (tempTable) that I just created with the Super_Avatar and Avatar tables through avName in the same query?.

Comment: You cannot create a tempTable and then JOIN/SELECT on it in the same query.  They will have to be separate queries or you can use a subquery to join.  Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: thanx for the advice..im new so im stil learnin to optimize navigatin and using the site..thnx again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert into a temp table and then select or join on it in the same query.  You can however, you a subquery or a CTE (depending on database):

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT avName
    FROM Trade
    GROUP BY avName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) t
inner join Avatar a
    on t.avName = a.avName
inner join Super_Avatar s
    on t.avName = s.avname
```

Since you are using MS Access, it requires parentheses around each join, so you should be able to use:

```
select *
from
((
    SELECT avName
    FROM Trade
    GROUP BY avName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) as t
inner join Avatar as a
    on t.avName = a.avName)
inner join Super_Avatar as s
    on t.avName = s.avname
```

Comment: no luck, im gettin a sytax error..it looks like Access doesn't accept anything after the close braket..

Comment: @Bob Hmm, that is strange I just created the three tables in MS Access 2010 and ran the query with no problems.

Comment: wow it worked!! Thanks a lot! I didn't refesh my browser before i replied..ur solution worked.

Comment: the only problem is that it makes a column a.avname and s.avname which contain same data..im tryin to work around it..

Comment: @Bob You need to change the `select *` to select the actual columns that you need.

Comment: thnx, you solved every problem i faced..n i did learn somethin..best wishes.

Comment: @Bob Happy to help, if you found this answer helpful consider accepting it via the checkmark to the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a common table expression you don't even need the temp table

```
with tempTable as (
  SELECT avName
  FROM Trade
  GROUP BY avName
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) 
select *
from other_table
  join tempTable on ...
```

(This is ANSI SQL and works on all modern DBMS)

Comment: ok i'l try it and get back to u, thnx 4 replying..IM USING Access 2010.

Comment: @Bob: I don't think MS Access supports CTEs.